# Handle exclamation mark after command definition as :wq

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a way to make handle the `!` after a command like `:wq!`. This is in order to make my own function for quitting and/or writing files. I tried this but of course, it didn't works :

```
command! -nargs=0 SQ    :call <SID>SaveAndQuit(0, 0)
command! -nargs=0 SWQ   :call <SID>SaveAndQuit(1, 0)
command! -nargs=0 SQ!   :call <SID>SaveAndQuit(0, 1)
command! -nargs=0 SWQ!  :call <SID>SaveAndQuit(1, 1)
```

with the function `function! <SID>SaveAndQuit( write, force )`. Is there a way to handle the `!`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use the `-bang` attribute, then pass it to your function, and handle the `!` in your function.

```
:h bang
```

e.g.

```
command ... -bang XYZ  call Function('foo', <bang>0)
```

your function:

```
func Function (argstr, bang)..
"here you check the a:bang to decide what should be done.
```